# How to tell PMD to ignore @PostConstruct Methods for unused Code

Tags: java, ejb, cdi, pmd

we have a project which is checked by PMD for violations of e.g. unused private methods. Our problem is that we don't know if it is possible to ignore private Methods which are annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

The rule is defined as following:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedPrivateMethod"/>
```

#### Edit:

My goal is to define it once to ignore annotated methods. I would like to prevent writing `@SupressWarnings` on every method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the hint and advice from HairyFotr i was able to configure my ruleset to ignore `private` methods with `@PostConstruct`.

The rule I had to use is:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedPrivateMethod">
    <properties> 
        <property name="violationSuppressXPath" 
            value="//ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/Annotation/MarkerAnnotation/Name[@Image='PostConstruct']" />
    </properties>
</rule>
```

Comment: I believe the value needs to start with double slashes ("//") instead of double colons ("::").

Answer (score 3):

[moz987's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919039/3104218) suppresses all UnusedPrivateMethod violations in a file as soon as there is at least one @PostConstruct annotation present. If you only want to suppress the violations coming from methods with a @PostConstruct annotation and keep the violations from methods without the annotation then you have to prepend the XPath with `ancestor::` instead of `//`.

Note: the example below uses the new rule reference of PMD 6.0.0.

```
  <rule ref="category/java/bestpractices.xml/UnusedPrivateMethod">
    <properties>
      <property name="violationSuppressXPath"
                value="ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/Annotation/MarkerAnnotation/Name[@Image='PostConstruct']" />
    </properties>
  </rule>
```

Comment: I used a similar XPath for a different rule and if you use PMD 7 then the `ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration` needs to be replaced by `ClassDeclaration`. The `@Image` also does not work for me so I replaced it with `SimpleName`. The best way how to debug it is extract XML from java file see https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_userdocs_extending_ast_dump.html